# refreshing changed db link source (oracle gateway to sql server)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, gateway, dblink

the question is pretty straightforward, - when I chance to change setting in oracle gateway to microsoft sql server (dg4msql) configuration (HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO) to another database on the same server, the database link does not always gets refreshed - sometimes new selects using that database link stay hooked to the old setting.
probably oracle gateway caches the connection settings in some way?
how do I clear the cache?
thanks

Comment: Are the sessions stopped when the change is made?

Comment: do you mean the sessions connected to Oracle at that time? i guess not. what you are saying is that the db link settings are pulled from the configuration file at the time of the opening of each session and not as a result of polling the config file at specific times? i guess it's very logical, but it didn't quite occur to me :) please can you write it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database links are kept open for the duration of a session. The gateway makes use of a database link so it is logical to state that if you change a gateway config, in order for it to be activated, you need to re-open the link.

Easiest is to stop and start the sessions but this can also be done by issuing an

```
alter system close database link linkname
```

See [Closing Database Links](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin004.htm#ADMIN12168) in the docu.

Comment: +1 for alternative way to close dblink - another very very crude way i was using was killing running oracle gateway processes on the server (...)